# CSS - display: none does not work

Tags: css

I am going to not show a link in case that the device width is less than `480px`. To do this, I have used the following CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    .container{
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    .content-area{
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    .hide-small{
        display: none;
    }

}
```

The HTML is:

```
<nav class="Nav-bar">
        <ul class="Group">

                <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li class="hide-small"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>   
        </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is `hide-small` class does not hide the link. 
I am sure respected css file is loaded on html page. But when i go to the `inspect -> Element` the `li` tag has not the `hide-small` class.
It presented the `li` like this without any class:

```
<li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Use your browser's element inspector to see whether the rule is applied at all, and whether maybe some other rules are overwriting it. Are you sure the CSS file is included in the page?

Comment: Also I'd add a space between `max-width:` and `480px` just to make sure, CSS parsing can be funny sometimes

Comment: Maybe you're testing on a device that has > 480px width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works ! ..

http://hpics.li/b181647
and
http://hpics.li/5ea4dc0

the display is on only when width is 480px or under

you can test the width with this:

```
<script>
        function getWidth() {
          if (self.innerHeight) {
            return self.innerWidth;
          }

          if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
            return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
          }

          if (document.body) {
            return document.body.clientWidth;
          }
        }

        alert(getWidth());
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably some other css property is overwriting your class. Try to force it using:

```
display: none !important;
```